# Self referencing a key in the object assignment

Tags: javascript, object, this

So I have had a quick look online and not found anyone suggesting what I have seen in the codebase I am working on and would like to know if what I am seeing is a good idea or does it have some possible side effects I don't know about.

The example below is common to what I see using the `const` NOT `this`. its more or less static (no real setters/getters).

```
const CSS = {
  something: '.something',
  getSomethingByAnother: another => `${CSS.something}*=${another}`,
};

module.exports = CSS;
```

The more suggested solution would be to use `this` not the `const`

```
const CSS = {
  something: '.something',
  getSomethingByAnother: function(another) {return `${this.something}*=${another}`;},
};

module.exports = CSS;
```

Comment: Would personally prefer `this` over the variable name, less refactoring to do imo

Comment: Thanks that is a good point, but as its in the code base already I was hopping for more of a, why I should keep or refactor this style. Are there dangers to it etc.

Comment: Actually, I gave you an incorrect answer. `this` won't reference `CSS` in the second example, but instead the parent context, since the arrow function preserves the main scope. You'd have to do something like `getSomethingByAnother(another) { return this.something... }` to properly use the `this` keyword. Running the second snippet should give you `undefined`. Hope that helps

Comment: Fixed `this.something === undefined` from @ShengSlogar comment